# Vuejs | Добавить/удалить класс родительскому элементу

Tags: javascript, vue.js

На проекте используется **bootstrap-vue.js**. Есть такая структура:

```
<div class="faq-container__item">
    <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 @click="openItem">
    <h4 class="h4" >текст</h4>
    </b-button>
    <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
    <div>
    <p class="card-text">текст</p>
    </div>
    </b-collapse>
</div>
<div class="faq-container__item">
    <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-2 @click="openItem">
    <h4 class="h4" >текст</h4>
    </b-button>
    <b-collapse id="collapse-2" class="mt-2">
    <div>
    <p class="card-text">текст</p>
    </div>
    </b-collapse>
</div>
```

Нужно по клику на кнопку добавить родительскому элементу (`faq-container__item`) класс `open`. Делаю так:

```
data() {
  return {
    openItem: function() {

      $('.btn').parent().toggleClass("open")

    }
  }
}
```

Класс `open` добавляется сразу все существующим `faq-container__item`. 
Как сделать чтобы класс добавлялся только родительскому элементу?

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html И юзать `jquery` с `vue`...Бяка)

Answer (score 1):

В Vue компоненте(экземпляре) есть свойство **methods**. Там и необходимо описывать методы.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      is_active: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  methods: {
    openItem() {
      this.is_active = !this.is_active;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.active{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div 
      class="faq-container__item"
      :class="{active: is_active}"
      >
      <h4 class="h4">
        <button 
          @click="openItem"
         >
          Текст
        </button>
      </h4>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067614/how-to-get-parent-of-clicked-element-in-vue-js

Comment: спасибо за ответ. но этот метод также добавляет класс всем .faq-container__item на странице. а нужно только родительскому

Comment: Так дайте ему название уникальное?

Comment: @voronovam Обновил ответ. Совсем забыл, что первым параметром прилетает event!)